# How to get absolute jar path of bundle by org.osgi.framework.Bundle Object?

Tags: osgi

I've got a org.osgi.framework.Bundle instance, and I tried

```
bundle.getLocation();
bundle.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

none of them can return the absolute path of the specific dependency jar file. So my question is how to get the path by this bundle instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot ... since stackoverflow wants 30 chars minimum ... you really cannot get it ... Frameworks are free to store the JARs any way they see fit.

Comment: Also, perhaps you should consider why you think you need the location of the bundle jar. If you need to locate content in the bundle, there are several API for that.